# google analytic, set and get new variable

Tags: google-analytics, google-api, google-analytics-firebase, google-analytics-filters

I wonder how to add new variable to analytic when user visit page.

```
 ga('set', 'userId', 'HP2202'); // Set the user ID using signed-in user_id.
  ga('_setCustomVar',
    1,
    'dimension1',
    'Member',
     2             // Sets the scope to session-level.  Optional parameter.
  );

  ga('send', 'pageview', {
    'dimension1':  'SKU12345'
  });
```

How could I know it success or not?

I using google analytic addon stylesheet to get report. where option I should add ga:dimension1 to ?

Comment: _setCustomVar is deprecated with Universal Analytics. Use a custom dimension instead.

Comment: thanks a lot @eike . I found document to do it :D